# Django: How to place a form in all subsites and process it on 1 url?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need to place a form in all my subsites and home page. It's placed on right column. It's action is `"/"`. If there are some errors I must display them.
I made Form class etc. I display it via `{{ form.as_p }}` and designed all.

The problem is - how to put it on all sites? I don't want to make form instance in all my views functions.

What is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a work for a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). :-)

```
def my_form_processor(request):
    return {'my_form': MyForm()}
```

Comment: So I need to write custom template processor?

Comment: @robos85 Yes. Or you can copy it from my answer. :-)

Comment: I was thinking so. But - I have that simple one, it just passes a basic form to template. What if someone fills my form and send it? In my view function i do all the stuff with validation. Then, if form is not valid, I need to pass it to template to show errors. But - in the same time I have a form instance from template processor. What then?

Comment: @robos85 I don't think it's good idea. If I have a huge page loaded, I won't be very happy to get it reloaded with "you forget to fill required field" message. It's better to show all errors at form's action view. And / or use JS / AJAX validation. If you still want to display erorrs at the same page reloaded, you should process the form by custom middleware.

Comment: My plan is to validate a form in 1 exact url so if user post it, he's redirected to specific page.
So - how to make it right? On site, where form is validated, I should overwrite that form and elsewhere use that one from template processor?
EDIT:
I made it that I use form from processors, and in validation url I made:
if request.method == 'POST': .... do form stuff
else:
    form = RequestContext(request).get('my_form', False)

Comment: @robos85 Yes, I think. Context processor will just put form instance into context, I don't think there's need to override something.

Comment: I need to override it because I pass all in 1 render_to_response.
It works now anyway, so thanks for advise :)